# Adding ActionListener to button

Tags: java, actionlistener

I have an app with 6 button using ShowLayout. When a button is pressed the button number is displayed in the console.

What's wrong with my code? I can't get it to work! The buttons show, but cant get actionListenerto work and display the number. Thanks!

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.*;


class ShowFlowlayout extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
JButton one = new JButton("One");
JButton two = new JButton("Two");
JButton three = new JButton("Three");
JPanel p2 = new JPanel();
JButton four = new JButton("Four");
JButton five = new JButton("Five");
JButton six = new JButton("Six");


public ShowFlowlayout() {

    this.setLayout (new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT, 10, 20));

    p1.add(one);
    p1.add(two);
    p1.add(three);
    p2.add(four);
    p2.add(five);
    p2.add(six);

    add(p1, FlowLayout.LEFT);
    add(p2, FlowLayout.CENTER);

}

 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource() == one)
        {
            System.out.println("Button One");
        }
        if(e.getSource() == two)
        {
            System.out.println("Button Two");
        }
        if(e.getSource() == three)
        {
            System.out.println("Button Three");
        }
        if(e.getSource() == four)
        {
            System.out.println("Button Four");
        }
        if(e.getSource() == five)
        {
            System.out.println("Button Five");
        }
        if(e.getSource() == six)
        {
            System.out.println("Button Six");
        }


    }  




public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    ShowFlowlayout frame = new ShowFlowlayout();

     frame.setTitle ("Programming 12.1");
     frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
     frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
     frame.setSize(440, 100);
     frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

`

Comment: Don't edit your question! Now it is useless for the community. Just vote up the responses you like and mark one as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Register the `ActionListener` with the buttons:

```
one.addActionListener(this);
two.addActionListener(this);
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually you are not adding the `ActionListener` to the buttons. Try like this:

```
public ShowFlowlayout() {

   this.setLayout (new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT, 10, 20)); 

   p1.add(one);
   p1.add(two);
   p1.add(three);
   p2.add(four);
   p2.add(five);
   p2.add(six);

   one.addActionListener(this);
   two.addActionListener(this);
   three.addActionListener(this);
   four.addActionListener(this);
   five.addActionListener(this);
   six.addActionListener(this);

   add(p1, FlowLayout.LEFT);
   add(p2, FlowLayout.CENTER);

}
```